# How to terminate MPI program which has forked another processes

Tags: c, linux, mpi, openmpi

I need to write a MPI program which has to just start few processes on different cluster nodes. This is my sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, size, nodenamesize;
    char nodename[100];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(nodename, &nodenamesize);

    printf("Hello world! I am %d of %d running on %s\n", rank, size, nodename);

    if (rank == 0) {
        system("./Longwait&");
    } else if (rank == 1) {
        system("./AnotherLongWait&");
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

It successfully start the processes but MPI application doesn't terminate itself. It waits even after the MPI_Finalize() is called;.

what is the wrong with this code? What do I need to do to have the MPI program has to just start some other applications but shouldn't wait for anything.

Thank you,
Regards, 
Robo.

Comment: Did you consider using `fork`, `execve` and `waitpid` system calls (hence avoiding the `system` library function), and communicate with your `*LongWait` processes using e.g. `pipe`-s perhaps with `poll` ?

Comment: yes, I have tried fork&execl too..If its normal process creations then parent exits as expected. but here, with MPI, MPI parent process doesn't exit until both "Longwait" & "AnotherLongWait" killed.

Comment: You need the MPI parent process to last as long as your `LongWait` is running. You cannot call `MPI_Finalize` before.

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit? Because, in this case, LongWait process is independent and standalone process doesn't depend on anything such as any MPI calls. I am using MPI program to just to trigger the application to start nothing else.

Comment: This is a very odd thing to do with MPI, well outside the normal uses to which it is put and probably not of great interest either to the developers of the standard nor to 99.99% of its users.  As one of the 99.99% I'm neither surprised nor perturbed that this piece of code doesn't (seem to) work.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Okay.. your argument might be correct. So in this situation, few cluster nodes are connected them self and wanted to execute shared tasks in parallel, how can the processes be triggered to start on all cluster nodes?

Comment: @RoboAlex: the usual approach with MPI is that all processes in the communicator execute the same program.  The MPI run-time system takes care of starting up all the processes involved and establishing the mechanisms for inter-process communication, which is done using MPI routines. If you want to manage processes executing different programs, you're probably better off without MPI.  This is not the place to teach you basic MPI programming, there's a slew of tutorials on the net such as: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, in fact he can. And it is the Open MPI ORTE runtime that waits for the child process to finish, not the actual MPI program - a simple `printf()` after `MPI_Finalize` or `strace` confirms that. By the way, calling `system(3)` from Open MPI applications running on nodes with InfiniBand connectivity could be very problematic.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the delay is the mechanism that Open MPI uses in order to provide I/O redirection. Tip: use `system("ls -l /proc/self/fd");` or `system("lsof -c lsof");` to get an idea of how many file descriptors are open in child processes spawned by `system(3)`. These descriptors are held open by both `Longwait` and `AnotherLongWait` which makes the MPI run-time wait for them to complete.

Here is a simple example with two very simple sample versions of `Longwait`:

Version 1: Sleeps 1 minute

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

If you spawn this program with `system("./Longwait&");` you will have to wait for it to first finish before `mpirun`/`mpiexec` would also finish.

Version 2: Blindly closes the first 20 file descriptors before sleeping

```
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main (void)
 {
     int i;

     for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
         close(i);
     sleep(60);
     return 0;
 }
```

If you spawn this program as before, the `mpirun`/`mpiexec` executable will finish shortly after the MPI program exits without waiting.

Now this is **not** a real solution - randomly closing open file descriptors can have unpredictable effects. Finding out which descriptors should be closed is neither easy nor portable. I would generally advise against doing what you do in your code. Besides Open MPI does not reliably support process forking on systems with InfiniBand interconnect (`system(3)` uses `fork(2)` behind the scenes).